# How does scope gets affected in nested functions in C?

Tags: c

```
int a=27;
f()
{
    int a=32;
    g();
}
g()
{
    print a;
    {
    int a=99;
    h();
    }
}
h()
{
    print a;
}
void main()
{
    print a;
    f();
    g();
    h();
}
```

I got the answers as 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27 for static scope and 27, 32, 99, 27, 99, 27 for dynamic scope. Am i correct?

Comment: There are no nested functions; and each function has its own variables - it does not matter if they share names. Variables that share the same names as those from outer lexical scopes - not execution contexts, C has no 'dynamic scope' - will shadow them.

Comment: What language? `print a` is not valid C.

Comment: C/C++ doesn't use Dynamic scoping. Your programming language will use one or the other, you don't get to choose

Comment: @JerryGoyal Never use perl? ;-}

Comment: @user2864740 never get the chance (or reason) :D

Comment: @JerryGoyal This code is not in C/C++, i just wanted to learn how static and dynamic scopes work on a piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C/C++ doesn't use Dynamic scoping so you'll always get same answer: 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27.
More light on scoping:

**Static scoping:**

```
const int b = 5;
int foo()
{
   int a = b + 5;
   return a;
}

int bar()
{
   int b = 2;
   return foo();
}

int main()
{
   foo(); // returns 10
   bar(); // returns 10
   return 0;
}
```

**Dynamic scoping** (not used in C/C++ ..for the sake of example)

```
const int b = 5;
int foo()
{
   int a = b + 5;
   return a;
}

int bar()
{
   int b = 2;
   return foo();
}

int main()
{
   foo(); // returns 10
   bar(); // returns 7
   return 0;
}
```

Dynamic scoping means that when a symbol is referenced, the compiler/interpreter will walk up the symbol-table stack to find the correct instance of the variable to use.

Comment: The explanation helped a lot. Out of confusion.